# discord py, try to send an image

Tags: python, discord.py

trying to send an image so

copied this code from a post and i added some.

```
ch = get(member.guild.channels, name="general")
# where i want to send an image 

#this is my animated gif from this line I copied but no idea where Image function come from 
image = Image.open("./images/welcome.gif")

with BytesIO() as image_binary:
   image.save(image_binary, "gif")
   image_binary.seek(0)
   await ch.send(file=discord.File(fp=image_binary))
```

I installed Image through pip 
and added 
import Image 
then got error

so I think that is not the module from pip

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want the `Pillow` library.

```
pip install Pillow
```

Then, import `Image` from `PIL`:

```py
from PIL import Image
```